# Ellucian Banner API

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I am new with banner student api. When I run the code below it gives me an error:
**ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis**

```
call sb_course.f_query_one(
            p_subj_code => "LMA",
            p_crse_numb => "400",
            p_eff_term  => 201203
            );
```

Thanks in advance for you time.

Comment: I even tried `call sb_course.f_query_one(
            p_subj_code => 'LM',
            p_crse_numb => '600P',
            p_eff_term  => 201300
            );` and gives same error message.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The small code snippet will not produce the error `ORA-00907: missing
right parenthesis`. That error is either from the context around the
code snippet, or within the code ran by calling `f_query_one`.

Below, I show

1. That double quotes around the values in the call do not work. In
   Oracle double quotes are a way to specify identifiers that do not
   follow the normal identifier rules. The error in this case is
   *ORA-06576: not a valid function or procedure name*
2. Using single quote works when calling a procedure.
3. When calling a function, an `into` clause needs to be specified to
   receive the return value. Otherwise the error *ORA-06576: not a valid
   function or procedure name* will be raised.

**In no case is *ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis* raised**
Please look at the wider context to find the cause of your error.

The following is the interaction with SQL*Plus. `SQL>` is a prompt for
new commands, with the lines below with numbers for additional lines
for that one command. Everything else is printed by SQL*Plus.

Make output from the `dbms_output` package visible.

```
SQL> set serveroutput on size unlimited
```

Create a procedure `f_query_one` taking the augments from your
sample. Types are guessed based on the values passed in your
sample. Note, I do not have an `SB_COURSE` schema. That will be a
difference from my samples below, and your code snippet.

```
SQL> create or replace procedure f_query_one(p_subj_code in varchar2
  2      , p_crse_numb in varchar2
  3      , p_eff_term in varchar2)
  4  is begin
  5      dbms_output.put_line('Hello World!');
  6  end f_query_one;
  7  /

Procedure created.
```

Call as posted in your question, and find that double quotes do not
work.

```
SQL> call f_query_one(
  2              p_subj_code => "LMA",
  3              p_crse_numb => "400",
  4              p_eff_term  => 201203
  5              );
            p_subj_code => "LMA",
                           *
ERROR at line 2:
ORA-06576: not a valid function or procedure name
```

Call with single quotes. Works!

```
SQL> call f_query_one(p_subj_code => 'LMA'
  2      , p_crse_numb => '400'
  3      , p_eff_term  => 201203);
Hello World!

Call completed.
```

Drop the procedure and create a function with the name `f_query_one`.

```
SQL> drop procedure f_query_one;

Procedure dropped.

SQL> create or replace function f_query_one(p_subj_code in varchar2
  2      , p_crse_numb in varchar2
  3      , p_eff_term in varchar2) return varchar2
  4  is begin
  5      return 'Hello World!';
  6  end f_query_one;
  7  /

Function created.
```

Call the function. But the function does exist, why does it say it does not?

```
SQL> call f_query_one(p_subj_code => 'LMA'
  2      , p_crse_numb => '400'
  3      , p_eff_term  => 201203);
call f_query_one(p_subj_code => 'LMA'
     *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-06576: not a valid function or procedure name
```

Create a bind variable. **`var` is a SQL*Plus command. It is part of
neither the SQL or PL/SQL languages.**

```
SQL> var so varchar2(20)
```

Add an `into` clause to save the value in the bind variable.

```
SQL> call f_query_one(p_subj_code => 'LMA'
  2      , p_crse_numb => '400'
  3      , p_eff_term  => 201203) into :so;

Call completed.
```

Print the bind variable. **`print` is a SQL*Plus command. It is part of
neither the SQL or PL/SQL languages.**

```
SQL> print so

SO
--------------------------------
Hello World!
```

Answer (score 1):

Using single quotes should work.  Are you sure the error is happening on this line?  What you written in your comment looks good.

Strike that.....

You do not want to use the word "call".  If you are writing in pl/sql, then drop that word.  If you are writing this in sql, then use "exec" instead.

Comment: Please let me know if this was correct.  :) I could use a few points.

Comment: `EXEC[UTE]` is neither a SQL or PL/SQL word, it is a SQL*Plus command: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_twelve022.htm#i2697931. "`CALL` is a SQL statement for executing a routine." http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/statements_4008.htm#BABDEHHG. I personally do not ever use `call` though people I work with do.

Comment: @BrianMcGinity I tried single quote as well and its gave me the same error.

Comment: @ShannonSeverance Thank for the info. I tried calling the procedure without `CALL` but i am still getting same error.

Comment: Is this a procedure? Because `f_` is sometimes used as prefix for function.

Comment: @Chorel Oh yes its a function.

Comment: Ah - that would be the problem.  In PL/SQL you cannot ignore the return value from a function - you MUST save the returned value into a variable, even if you never use it (and if you never use the value, the compiler will politely let you know about this, too :-).

Comment: @AvineshKumar - In that case you need to provide variable for return value. A good example is provided by ShannonSeverance's answer.